# How do I import React component based on a dependancy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I'm using React (babel) and jsx for the first time and Webpack for creating my `bundle.js`

I've crated two React components - Header1.jsx and Header2.jsx.

If before 4.July 2016 -> use Header1.jsx
If after 4.July 2016 -> use Header2.jsx

To import the components into React I'm using index.js:

```
import SportMenu from './components/SportMenu.jsx';
import NextMatches from './components/NextMatches.jsx';
(...)
```

Basically I want a code that does this:

```
var eventStart = new Date('2016-06-10T21:00:00+02:00');
var now = new Date();

if(nowgetDate().getDate() < eventStart.getDate()){
    import EmCountdown from './components/Countdown.jsx';
} else {
    import FocusMenu from './components/FocusMenu.jsx';
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't import modules dynamically, however you can import them as usual modules

```
import SportMenu from './components/SportMenu.jsx'; 
import NextMatches from './components/NextMatches.jsx'; 
import EmCountdown from './components/Countdown.jsx'; 
import FocusMenu from './components/FocusMenu.jsx';
```

and then render them by condition

```
var eventStart = new Date('2016-06-10T21:00:00+02:00');
var now = new Date();

if (now < eventStart){
    <EmCountdown />; 
} else {
    <FocusMenu />;
}
```